# Why does Scipy rv_discrete always return 1

Tags: python, arrays, scipy, statistics

I'm trying to form the distribution of a random variable. Where the probability that a reaction fires is:

Prob(Rj fires) = aj/a0

aj = a propensity function, that describes the probability an individual reaction fires in a given time period.

a0 = the sum of all the propensity functions for all the reactions in the system.

At the moment I have a function that returns an array of propensity functions for each reaction in the systems, which outputs:

```
[32.  0.  0.]
```

I have then used a0 = sum(propensity) to calculate a0. which is followed by a second function:

```py
def prob_rxn_fires(propensity, a0):
    prob = propensity/a0   
    return prob
```

To calculate aj/a0, the output of this function is assigned to the variable: rxn_probability. 
There are three reactions in my system and I'm now trying to use scipy.stats.rv_discrete to sample from the distribution.

I have the number of reactions in the system stored in the array:

```
num_rxn = np.arange(1, rxn_probability.size + 1).reshape(rxn_probability.shape)
```

which is shaped and sized so it always matches with the rxn_probability array.

My code at the moment is:

```
j = stats.rv_discrete(name="Reaction index", values=(num_rxn, rxn_probability)).rvs()
```

but the output is always 1 and I'm not sure if thats right and if not why its not right ?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you have the following arrays:

```py
import numpy as np

rxn_probability = np.array([1, 0, 0])

num_rxn = np.arange(1, rxn_probability.size + 1).reshape(rxn_probability.shape)
num_rxn 
array([1, 2, 3])
```

Therefore when using `rv_discrete` with `values=(num_rxn, rxn_probability)` you are basically saying that with probablity one it should pick the 0-th element of `num_rxn`.

Now if you try different values, let's say `values=(num_rxn, [.8, .1, .1])` the result would be:

- 1 with probability .8
- 2 with probability .1
- 3 with probability .1

If you want a uniform distribution, you can specify  `values=(num_rxn, [1/3] * num_rxn.size)`.